# Returning undefined as the sequence of code is not getting followed in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have a service which brings a promise and in that promise there is a boolean value which i want to assign to another variable which is needed in the whole code.

What i did was tried calling the service in the constructor but if i do console.log() in that service.then()it gets printed after everything is complete.

```
//this is in the constructor
private ecr;
{let res=this.config.getImageConfig("getConfig").then((response:boolean)=>{
      this.ecr=response;
      console.log("response",response);
    })
    res.resolve(()=>{
      this.patchRequestServices();
    })
}

private getany(){
console.log(this.ecr);// shows undefined;
....
//patchRequestServices has functions like getany()
//I cannot make getany async as this function returns some data which is directly used in the code somewhere else
```

Comment: You need to learn about Promises (and should use async/await).

Comment: i tried using async await on getany function but this function is used in many different places in the code so i am not able to make that function async.